# How to prove the given sets are equal?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

[image]

I did not understand the highlighted part(in red).

1. How is the equality obtained? One inclusion is clear namely, the left hand side is a subset of the right hand side.
2. Why is this an open subset of R^n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two set-theoretic facts to use here:

1. The preimage of an intersection is the intersection of the preimages.
2. If some subset $B$ lies in the image of a map $f$, then $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$.

Applying these to our bijection $\phi: U \to \phi(U)$, we get
$$\phi^{-1}\big(\phi(U) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\})\big)\overset{(1)}{=}\phi^{-1}(\phi(U)) \cap \phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\})=U \cap (U \cap N)=U \cap N.$$
Working from right to left, hit the whole thing with $\phi$ again:
$$\phi(U \cap N)=\phi\big(\phi^{-1}\big(\phi(U) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\})\big)\big)\overset{(2)}{=} \phi(U) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\}).$$

As for your second question, recall that charts are defined to be homeomorphisms from open subsets of your manifold to open subsets of a Euclidean space. So $\phi(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{m-n}$, hence the intersection $\phi(U) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\}$ by the definition of the subspace topology.

Comment: instead of using property 2 can't we just say that phi and phi^(-1) cancel out each other ,being a homeomorphism?

Comment: @RagingBull: It doesn't sound like you're requiring your charts to be homeomorohisms onto $\mathbb{R}^m$ itself, just an open set thereof.